# How can one simplify the following expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the expression:

$$-\left(\frac{A}{3a} + \frac{B}{3b} + \frac{C}{3c}\right) \pm \frac{8}{3} \sqrt{b^{2}c^{2}A^{2} + a^{2}c^{2}B^{2} + a^{2}b^{2}C^{2} - abc^{2}AB - ab^{2}cAC - a^{2}bcBC}$$

and I would like to be able to simplify it, if it is at all possible.

Thank you.

Comment: "Equation" is the wrong word here.  "Expression" would fit.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, I see. I will edit the post appropriately. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

$$-\left(\frac{A}{3a} + \frac{B}{3b} + \frac{C}{3c}\right) \pm \frac{8}{3} \sqrt{{a^2b^2c^2}\left(\frac{A^2}{a^2} +\frac{B^2}{b^2}  + \frac{C^2}{c^2} - \frac{AB}{ab} - \frac{AC}{ac} - \frac{BC}{bc}\right)},$$

$$-\left(\frac{A}{3a} + \frac{B}{3b} + \frac{C}{3c}\right) \pm \frac{8|abc|}{3} \sqrt{\frac{A^2}{a^2} +\frac{B^2}{b^2}  + \frac{C^2}{c^2} - \frac{AB}{ab} - \frac{AC}{ac} - \frac{BC}{bc}},$$

Comment: Wow, that is really neat! Thank you, @Essam. However, is this as far as one can simplify the expression, in your opinion?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Oh, so is this incorrect?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Ah, I see.